# C#,Multiple condition for if statement

Tags: c#

I am a matlab user. How can I use the following if statment in c#

```
    double angle;
    //angle=45.00;// just for idea
        if (0.0<=angle<90.0)||(170.0<=angle<181.0)
        {
// do something
        }
```

// It is just demo code what I want to do.......

Comment: Have you done any investigation into how to do multiple conditions in if statements in C#?

Answer (score 2):

The syntax you used can't work in C#. The easiest solution is:

```
if (((angle >= 0) && (angle < 90)) || ((angle >= 170) && (angle < 181)))
{
    // your code here
}
```

Using literals on your condition constants, you can achieve the same result without implicit casting from Int32 to Double (a little bit better performance-wise, but almost unnoticeable):

```
if (((angle >= 0.0d) && (angle < 90.0d)) || ((angle >= 170.0d) && (angle < 181.0d)))
{
    // your code here
}
```

An alternative approach:

```
public static Boolean Between(this Double num, Double lower, Double upper, Boolean inclusive = false)
{
    return inclusive
        ? lower <= num && num <= upper
        : lower < num && num < upper;
}
```

Then:

```
if (angle.Between(0.0d, 90.0d) || angle.Between(170.0d, 181.0d))
{
    // your code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't combine comparisons like that in C#:

```
if ((0 <= angle && angle < 90) || (170 <= angle && angle < 181)
{
    // do something
}
```